# SnapLogic - Altering array elements in Mapper

Tags: arrays, json, mapping, snaplogic

I currently have an incoming `.json` file that I am routing through a **Mapper** snap. In that mapper snap, I need to take an array of names `bob.jones`, `eric.smith`, etc, and add the string `@email.com` to each of them. The path for these names in the schema is:

```
jsonPath($, "$response.entity[*].target.name")
```

And the structure looks like this:

```
{
    "entity": [
        {
            "target": {
                "name": "bob.jones"
            }
        },
        {
            "target": {
                "name": "eric.smith"
            }
        },
        ...
    ]
}
```

Just mapping the path `jsonPath($, "$response.entity[*].target.name")` will pass the names and output `bob.jones` and `eric.smith`.  I tried to use `.concat()` on the array but all that did was add `@email.com` into the list so I got `bob.jones, eric.smith, @email.com`. I am trying to figure out an expression that can edit the array items without changing their structure.

Comment: Can you also share the expected output JSON?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the JSON path provided by you - `jsonPath($, "$response.entity[*].target.name")` - I created the following JSON.

```
{
    "response": {
        "entity": [
            {
                "target": {
                    "name": "bob.jones"
                }
            },
            {
                "target": {
                    "name": "eric.smith"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

And I put it in a JSON Generator so that I can get it as documents. Refer to the following screenshot.

[image: JSON Generator]

If your desired output is as follows:

[image: mapper case 1]

Then use the following expression in the mapper.

```
$response.entity.map(e => e.target.name + '@email.com')
```

Else if your desired output is as follows:

[image: mapper case 2]

Then use the following setting in your mapper.

[image: mapper case 2 setting]